# Running Rails unit tests on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I've deployed an app to Heroku, and it all works fine. The problem is I can't get my unit tests running remotely. I've tried:

```
heroku rake test:units
```

and

```
heroku rake db:test:prepare
```

but for both I get a massive stack trace, ending with:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/app/[id]/home/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:429:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
```

I'm running the `bamboo-mri-1.9.2` stack.

The closest I've got to an answer so far is [this blog post from 2009](http://blog.angelbob.com/posts/7-Heroku-and-unit-tests---heroku-testing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heroku doesn't provide a testing database, so there's no straightforward way to do that.  You could theoretically create a new heroku instance and hack up the rake tasks to just use the 'production' database possibly, but I doubt the effort required would be worth it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had a similar [answer from @eden on Twitter](http://twitter.com/#!/aeden/status/38376111813558272).

Comment: Turns out this is also the error if you don't have a test database configured in database.yml locally.  Thanks, you solved my unrelated problem!

Answer (score 6):

Heroku devcenter provides an explanation about how managing a staging environment here : http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments

I don't know if it possible to run unit tests but I perfectly understand why you want to do this.

Your Heroku application:

- may have different gems from you local system (as far as I know, if you develop under Windows, your Gemfile.lock is ignored)
- may have a different OS (some Ruby libraries as IO does not behave exactely the same way on Windows and Linux)
- may have a different ruby version
- may have a different database system (it seems not so easy to use a local database with the exact same configuration as the one you use on Heroku)
- more generally speaking, will run on a different system (Linux version, ImageMagick, etc.)

You can test all that with a staging environment but we could say that for every unit test, so I think it would be great if we could run unit test on Heroku.

Answer (score 5):

The normal way is to do the testing locally, then deploy to a hidden Heroku instance ("staging"). Then you can test that hidden staging app with your beta testers, run stress tests on it and so on. If you are satisfied with it, deploy your app to your "production" Heroku instance.

So testing on Heroku is possible and usual, but not with unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku does not have the test suite, you really should be testing on development side before deployment to heroku.

Comment: Thanks - I am testing locally, but I thought it would be worth testing on Heroku as well. Guess not!

Comment: Yeah generally speaking I have never had to test in production.  It comes down to writing or rather over writing tests. I use rspec & autotest.  Autotest is great because its constantly running your tests in the background. You can read more about it in [Rails Tutorial - Testing](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:testing_tools)

Comment: Of course you want to run your automated tests against your staging app. Not doing it would be a total waste. What’s the purpose of having a staging app if you’re not going to run tests against it? So you can run manual tests? Uh... well, then why did you go through all the trouble of automating them? This just doesn’t make any sense to me.

Comment: so the answer to this is that you can't run automated tests on the heroku staging environment? This does seem like a huge waste indeed.