# How do you run rspec and cucumber on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, heroku, cucumber

I'd like to be able to run rspec and cucumber on my staging app on Heroku. I have a separate production app and I push my development branch to staging and my master branch to production.

I have set the RACK_ENV variable to 'staging' and have also added a staging.rb config file.

**Running rspec and cucumber locally:**

Both rspec and cucumber run fine locally using the commands

```
$ rspec spec
```

..

```
$ cucumber features
```

**Running rspec on Heroku staging app**

The problem is that I can't get them to run on my Heroku staging app. I understand that the correct way to rspec on Heroku is:

```
$ heroku rake spec --remote staging
```

Whenever I run this though I get the following errors:

```
rake aborted!
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:429:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:460:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
(in /app)
```

**Running cucumber on Heroku staging app**

Similarly:

```
$ heroku rake cucumber --remote staging
```

Results in:

```
rake aborted!
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:429:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:460:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `call'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:634:in `block in execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:629:in `execute'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:595:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:605:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:602:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:594:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:588:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:581:in `invoke'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2041:in `invoke_task'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2019:in `block in top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2013:in `top_level'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1992:in `run'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
(in /app)
```

The issue is clearly something to do with the database but I'm not sure how to address it.

Comment: Do you have settings for `staging` in your `database.yml`?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to run these on Heroku? It's not necessarily a bad idea since there may be differences to your development platform, but I'm just wondering what your thinking is, as most people will just run them locally and in a continuous integration environment such as Hudson.

Comment: Hi Thomas, given the slight differences with Heroku - different connections to external services, different database; I would like to run the tests on there to be sure that everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that testing uses a separate database, not the one on which the application is running. This second database you don't get on Heroku. See [Running Rails unit tests on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035828/running-rails-unit-tests-on-heroku/5036501#5036501) for the answer to a similar question.

Comment: Thank you for that. If one did just use a separate instance on heroku could you just use the production database on that instance for testing?

Comment: You could create a separate instance for testing, set the RACK_ENV to 'testing' and then use the production database for it (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981508/share-database-between-2-apps-in-heroku/5981700#5981700), but be careful, running the tests will wipe the database clean every time you run them.